# Box Collider snapping to Tile Collider but not other Box Colliders. PHYSICS MATERIAL NOT WORKING

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://gyazo.com/4715b11e322ff556113efcba3899bba6
On the right is the box collider, working fine colliding with the player.
On the left is the tilemap collider, where the player snaps into the wall until I let go of arrow key.

Here is movement script:

```cs
public float movementSpeed = 10f;
    private float jumpThreshold = 0.01f;
    public float jumpHeight = 5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Debug.Log(Physics2D.gravity.y);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y > -jumpThreshold && rb.velocity.y < jumpThreshold)
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, -jumpHeight, 0f));
        transform.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
```

Comment: If you claim `Physics Materials not working` it would be good to know a) your physics material settings and b) what you expect it do achieve vs what happens instead. Also please forget about this line `transform.position` this breaks the physics .. you rather want to use `rb.MovePosition(rb.position + ...)` here!

Comment: I've read solutions as to put physics materials with minimal friction on all walls, and this simply doesn't work for me. Also it seems your `rb.MovePosition()` method screws with gravity and collisions...